# Perl "qr" what must not match

Tags: regex, perl

When I write:

```
myfunc(some => qr { \.(aa|bb|cc)$ }i );
```

it regex will match anything what ends to the `.aa` or `.bb` or `.cc` - case insensitive.

How to write, the exact opposite - eg. match anything other, e.g. what doesn't ends to `.aa` or `.bb` or `.cc` - again case insensitive?

The:

```
myfunc(some => qr { !/\.(aa|bb|cc)$/i } );
```

doesn't works.

How to write the correct `qr` to pass as the value to `some`?

Answer (score 2):

You need the [negative look-behind assertion](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Look-Around-Assertions):

```
qr/(?<!\.(?:aa|bb|cc))$/i
```

This regexp matches end of the string that does not follow `".aa"`, etc. But it works only for fixed-width look-behind.

Or if they’re not all the same length:

```
qr/(?<!\.(?:aa|bb|cc))(?<!\.ddd)$/i
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my $re = qr{ \.(?:aa|bb|cc)$ }xi;  !/$re/
```

can be written as

```
my $re = qr{ ^ (?! .* \.(?:aa|bb|cc)$ ) }sxi;  /$re/
```